# Convergence of series $\sum \left[(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n\right] $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to test convergence of $\sum u_n $ where $ u_n= {(n^3+1)^{(1/3)}} - n $

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $u_n>0$ you can use the Asymptotic Comparison Test:
$$u_n=n\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{1/3}-1\right)=n\left(1+\frac{1}{3n^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)-1\right)=\frac{1}{3n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\sim \frac{1}{3n^2}.$$
Therefore your series is equivalent to $\sum_n 1/n^2$ which is convergent.

P.S. More generally if $u_n= {(n^a+1)^{(1/a)}} - n$ with $a>0$ then in a similar way you will find that $u_n\sim \frac{1}{an^{a-1}}$. Hence $\sum_n u_n$ is convergent iff $a>2$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{split} u_n & =\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}-n \\
&=\dfrac{(n^3+1)-n^3}{(n^3+1)^{2/3}+n(n^3+1)^{1/3}+n^2}\\
& = \dfrac {1}{(n^3+1)^{2/3}+n(n^3+1)^{1/3}+n^2}\\
& <\dfrac{1}{3n^2}\end{split}$$

Since $\sum\dfrac1{3n^2}$ converges, so does $\sum u_n$.